# Is there a way to return a Type that is a subclass?

Tags: c#, generics

I want a function that basically does this:

```
public static Type GetProductType(int id)
{
    var typeString = db.GetTypeString(id);
    return Type.GetType(typeString);
}
```

which I want to use like this:

```
public static Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    var productType = GetProductType(id);
    return db.Table<productType>()
        .Single(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

But the problem with that is `p.id` in `.Single(p => p.id == id)`. The code has no awareness that p (that is, productType) has an id property. So one way I can think of to make this work is to have the `Type` that gets returned by `GetProductType` be constrained to a subclass of `Product` (which has an Id property).

It's setup like this because I'm using sql-net-pcl (sqliite for xamarin) and don't have access to entity framework. I need a type that maps to a table before I can do any queries. Instead of writing the same code for each product type I'm trying to write the code for `Product` and then lookup the specific product type based on the product's id.

Comment: Seems nore of a scenario where an interface would make more sense e.g. `IProduct`, you could then hard cast to whatever product type from the calling code.

Comment: If you know the Type is a Product sub-type, then why not return Product, rather than Type from your GetProductType function?

Comment: GetProductType looks at ProductType_View which only contains the product number and product type.

Comment: It looks like you want to call `db.Table<T>` except you're not specifying `T` at compile time. At runtime you want to pass a variable of type `Type` and then call `dbTable<T>` where `T` is the type specified by the variable. This is technically possible but not a "normal" solution to any problem. I apologize if this sounds less then helpful, but don't solve this problem. Take a step back and  write this so that you don't have this problem to solve.

Comment: You can't have *both* compile-time type safety *and* manipulation of types at runtime via reflection.  C# is optimized for the former.  I would think hard about whether this is the right approach in this language.

Comment: @EricLippert you're right. When I marked this as answered I had a typo in the code that caused it to compile (ProductType instead of productType (ProductType is a class)). I'm just clarifying for the sake of this post, really. I guess I could do the compile time part in a switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a base interface, where you define your product has an `Id` property:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Define your actual classes, and make sure they implement `IProduct`:

```
public class FruitProduct : IProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Variety { get; set; }
}

public class CerealProduct : IProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int SugarContent { get; set; }
}
```

And your final lookup, which will specify it's a type of `IProduct` (Thus giving you access to the Id field, which should be present on any `FruitProduct` or `CerealProduct` you send to `ProductLookup`)

```
public class ProductLookup<T> where T : IProduct
{
    public static T GetProduct(int id)
    {
        // var productType = GetProductType(id);
        //You can pass either FruitProduct or CerealProduct here (Although, you will ONLY
        //be able to access Id here, as this function only knows it's an IProduct)
        return this.db<T>()
            .Single(p => p.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man, I forgot how to add properties to an interface. I thought you couldn't do that. It works. Thanks!